# Stop PyCharm's Autocomplete from Overwriting Code in front of my Cursor

Tags: python, pycharm, code-completion

I am using PyCharm to write some python code and notice that I run into the following problem quite often:

I write a line of code like this

```
for item in myList:
```

Later, I realize that I would like the index of `item` as well, so I try to turn that line into this:

```
for i,item in enumerate(myList):
```

In order to turn the first line into the second, I put the cursor to the left of `item` and type `i,`. Then, I put the cursor to the left of `myList` and type `enu`; by this time, the code-completer suggests that I might want to type `enumerate`, which is exactly the behavior that I'm after. When I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to implement the suggested `enumerate`, I notice that my line turns into

```
for i,item in enumerate:
```

**The `myList` has been overwritten!**
The behavior that I expect is this:

```
for i,item in enumerate(myList):
```

with the cursor immediately to the right of either the `myList` or the `:`.

Is there any way that I could make Pycharm behave according to my expectations?

Just in case it matters, my dev environment is Mac OSX 10.7.5 (Lion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ autocompletion replacing the subsequent word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424303/intellij-autocompletion-replacing-the-subsequent-word)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This behavior is by design when you complete using <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Please use <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of Tab to insert the completion variant instead of overwriting.

Code completion settings dialog also has an option to insert variant by typing dot, space, etc.

Comment: Is there a way I can swap these behaviors?

Comment: @canyon289 [There is!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35425878/1344955) This has been driving me mad for ages, and I just took the time to find some kind of solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is default behaviour in PyCharm, if you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> while being connected to another word like so `en|myList`, then `myList` will get deleted.

What you *can* do is this, double-click `myList`, press <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, and then press <kbd><-</kbd>. Then just type in `enumerate`.

If you do this regularly, then you can just make a live template that surrounds.

Comment: The idea of `a live template that surrounds` is very attractive to me. How might I go about making such a live template to override the default [TAB] behavior? Also, I am on a mac (question updated), and `CTRL+ALT+T` does not work (nor does `CMD+ALT+T`). What would the analogous Mac keyboard shortcut be?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-code-constructs-using-surround-templates.html

Comment: @inspectorG4dget If you face any problems, invite me to a chat-room, or something, and we can sort it out.

Comment: I just created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39563/pycharm-codecompletion) and would appreciate your inputs