# IntelliJ autocompletion replacing the subsequent word

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete, jetbrains-ide

I've been using IntelliJ for a while now, but there's always been something that bothers me. Its to do with the autocomplete feature. This gif should be enough to illustrate.

[image]

In essence, when typing a word next to another one (that is with no space in between) regardless of the two words or the context, be it keywords or variables, the autocomplete will replace the next word by the one you complete with. I/m surprised that IntelliJ doesn't have a setting for that (at least not that I'm aware of) considering Eclipse does...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This behavior depends on the key that you use to select the item from the completion list. If you press Enter, the selected item is inserted in the code before the following identifier. If you press Tab, the selected item replaces the identifier following the cursor.

If you prefer, you can change the behavior by reassigning keyboard shortcuts for "Choose Lookup Item" and "Choose Lookup Item Replace" under Settings | Keymap.

Comment: Swapping these two is perfect! Replace makes more sense 99% of the time.

Comment: Thank you!  This has annoyed me for years, and I just thought to google it.  Turns out, your solution works great.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm tempted to swap them, but much more prefer to learn and get used to the defaults. That way you can easily pair on other peoples' machines. If anything, we should petition IntelliJ to swap the two!

Comment: @qwertzguy Replace makes more sense? What? In 8 years of using PhpStorm professionally I have literally never once, not even a single time, actually wanted to replace the next word with tab-complete. In 100% of cases I only wanted to insert the auto-filled word. I can't imagine a situation where replace makes more sense.

Comment: @Clonkex First thing is even with replace mode, if there is a space/comma/bracket it will insert and not replace, so it's very intuitive and you can just use the same shortcut every time. Second thing is an example of why replace is needed: I want to change obj.myfunc1() to obj.myfunc2(), I will set the cursor after the dot, look at completion and want to replace the existing function call. Same with replacing arguments: obj.func(var1) to obj.func(var2), I would never want to get obj.func(var1var2), it would never make sense, but that is what insert mode would do.